# How do you add an n-long list of arguments to a flag via argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

So far I have `def main(input_dir=None, output_dir=None):` in my code and later on I have;

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input_dir')
    parser.add_argument('output_dir')
    main(**vars(parser.parse_args()))
```

This works perfectly fine, but I'd like to add some flags. I'm unsure of how to go about it.
I've tried `parser.add_argument('-b', '--blacklist', nargs='*', type=str)`, but then it doesn't parse.

What I want to do is to be able to run `./script.py input_dir output_dir` or `./script.py input_dir output_dir -b do re mi fa so la si do` (`./script.py input_dir output_dir --blacklist do re mi fa so la si do` as well) and have "do re mi fa so la si do" stored in a set list `["do,"re","mi","fa","so","la","si","do"]` which I can access in `main()`.

### Solution

Add a `parser.add_argument('-b', '--blacklist', nargs='+')` and modify `def` to `def main(input_dir=None, output_dir=None, blacklist=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parser.add_argument('-b', '--blacklist', nargs='+', type=str)
...
args = parser.parse_args()
main(**vars(args))
```

As per the documentation vars() converts the NameSpace to a dict

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. I see the advantage of using + instead of *, but how do I change `main(**vars(parser.parse_args()))` and how do I access the variable in `main()`?

Comment: Sorry but this is clearly explained in argparse official documentation. Argparse will return a NameSpace object with each of your args names  as keys and whatever is entered as values.

Comment: I get a `TypeError: main() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Namespace` error.

Comment: Edited again, however, I would suggest that your main() takes the NameSpace as parameter and then you can just access each subkey with the dotted notation, i.e, args.blacklist, args.input_dir,...

Comment: `dict` gave me this error: `TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable` I'm not too familiar with `argparse` and I can't seem to wrap my head around the docs. How would I do what you suggested?

Comment: Yes, you must use vars() as you wrote initially, I've checked the doc. So **vars(args) shouldn't thrown any error. But if I was you I'd directly pass args and then access each parameter by its name like args.blacklist etc, in the main.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to have `main(**vars(args))`: this is what worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input_dir')
parser.add_argument('output_dir')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--blacklist', nargs='*', type=str)  
args = parser.parse_args()
print args   # good debugging practice

def main(input_dir=None, output_dir=None, **kwargs):
    print input_dir, output_dir
    print kwargs

main(**vars(args))
```

produces:

```
2146:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack26129093.py input output
Namespace(blacklist=None, input_dir='input', output_dir='output')
input output
{'blacklist': None}

2146:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack26129093.py input output -b do re me
Namespace(blacklist=['do', 're', 'me'], input_dir='input', output_dir='output')
input output
{'blacklist': ['do', 're', 'me']}
```

You could make `blacklist=None` an argument for `main`, but `**kwargs` is a handy way of passing in a number of optional arguments.

The use of `nargs='+'` v `'*'` doesn't matter much.  `'*'` just allows `prog input output -b`, producing `blacklist=[]`.

Looks like the main issues here are defining a function that takes various keyword arguments.  The `argparse` portion is straight forward.  `parse_args` gives you a `Namespace` object, which is easily turned into a dictionary with `vars(args)`.  It is also easy to access the `Namespace` values directly:

```
 args.input_dir
 args.output_dir # 'output'
 args.blacklist  # ['do', ...]
```

So `main` could also be written as:

```
def main(args):
    print args.input_dir
    ...
```